# How can I make Form1 disappear and Form2 appear automatically after ProgressBar hits 100%?

Tags: delphi

I created `Form1` and put a ProgressBar on it that moves from 1-100% with a timer, and put this code in it:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBar1.Position + 1;
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(ProgressBar1.Position) + ' %';
  if ProgressBar1.Position = 100 then
    Button1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

The interval value of the timer is 50, so that when it becomes 100% the button activates, and when I press it then Form2 appears by this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.ShowModal;
end;
```

But I want to delete the button, and I want it to happen automatically without a button, so that when the program is running, `Form1` appears, and the ProgressBar moves from 1% to 100%, then Form1 disappears and Form2 appears.

How can I do this?

I tried this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBar1.Position + 1;
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(ProgressBar1.Position) + ' %';
  if ProgressBar1.Position = 100 then
  begin
    Form1.Close;
    Form2.Show;
  end;
end;
```

But when executing the program, it hangs, and I get infinite messages (infinite loop), and I don't know why?

What is the solution?

Comment: You will learn all this if you find and read a good book about Delphi programming -- from the first page to the last page.

Comment: And while you are looking for the good book and reading it, you can take a sneak peek in Help and read what it says about the close method of a form. Then look (still in Help) for an alternative method to hide form1 before showing form2.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown should not *hang* the app.  However, it does have a couple of problems.

The biggest problem is that you are leaving the timer running, so it will continuously close `Form1` and show `Form2` every 50ms since the ProgressBar's `Position` stays at 100.

Also, assuming `Form1` is your `MainForm`, then closing the `MainForm` will terminate your process by default.

Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBar1.Position + 1;
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(ProgressBar1.Position) + ' %';
  if ProgressBar1.Position = 100 then
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
    Self.Hide;
    Form2.Show;
  end;
end;
```